# The Collector shows the GOG footage of a huge guy destroying a planet with the Infinity Stone. Who is this?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, character-identification, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

Shortly after the Guardians meet the Collector, he opens the sphere and explains that it contains an infinity stone. He shows the guys some footage of the infinity stone in action:

*A huge guy in armour slams a staff down into the ground in front of him, the infinity stone is embedded in said staff. The whole planet pretty much explodes.*

**Who is this guy in the armour?**

He very much resembles [Destroyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destroyer_(Thor)) from Thor (the original comic version, not the movie one). Does he exist in any canon or is he only added to the movie to show us what this infinity stone can do?

[image]

Comment: Related, possible dupe (right now, I'd vote no): [Which Celestial's head is “Knowhere”?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73521/which-celestials-head-is-knowhere)

Comment: As stated below, he's one of the Celestials. The fact that he looks like the Destroyer armor is a coincidence, although the armor WAS originally created to fight Celestials.

Comment: Better question: If the planet was destroyed, how'd he get that footage?

Comment: @jwodder the camera was sending the footage directly to a satellite in orbit?

Comment: @jwodder they must have the same search crews from Cloverfield and Rec and Blair Witch

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Marvel wikia names him as [Eson the Searcher](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Eson_the_Searcher#cite_note-0), one of the [Celestials](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Celestials).

Guardians Director James Gunn confirmed his identity in [this interview](http://www.thehollywoodnews.com/2014/11/17/guardians-of-the-galaxy-2-wont-center-on-star-lords-father-says-gunn/):

> “Maybe at some point, yeah,” he replied. “I mean, **I love that guy
>   (Eson the Searcher) that we see in the Collector’s lab. I love that
>   character. I think he’s really cool.** The visual effects artists did a
>   great job with him, and they were given a pretty big task, to create
>   this character in a short amount of time and put him in there. Yeah, I
>   like that stuff, the Celestials. I like the whole idea that the
>   Guardians are a bunch of mortals playing in the field of gods. It’s
>   really about their mortality in the face of all that stuff that makes
>   it both dramatic and fun.”

What he's "searching" for isn't mentioned but we've actually met this character before in [Eternals (v1) #9](http://www.comicvine.com/the-eternals-9-the-killing-machine/4000-17268/) from 1977:

[image]

Comment: Excellent man, cheers Richard! And thanks for adding the screenshot, much appreciated.

Comment: For just a bit of fun, note the shape of Eson's staff; [Galatus headshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bd0hX.jpg)

Comment: Ha... intentional? I'd say so.

Comment: @Daft - Oh yes. There's no way this shape crept in by accident.

Comment: @Richard: Which would imply that Galactus has an Infinity Stone in his head in the MCU? Or the Celestials were fighting Galactus by destroying planets before he could feed on them, and his shape was naturally suited to the task?

Comment: @JamesSheridan - Or that Eson was mocking Galactus.

Comment: @Richard: Celestial or not, I doubt that's a good idea.

Comment: @JamesSheridan Galactus won't exist in the MCU any time soon; as a Fantastic Four-derived character Fox has the movie rights to him.

Comment: @MartianInvader - That doesn't mean that they can't use him, just that it would cost them money. Evidently, there have been discussions about crossovers in the past; http://screenrant.com/marvel-crossover-event-movies-eventually/

Comment: @Richard Hence my qualifier, "any time soon". The article you link seems to agree. :)

Comment: @MartianInvader: Huh, I knew about *X: Men*, etc., but somehow had it in my head that *Marvel* retained the rights to the *F4*. I guess the original films were so bad I forgot who made them.

Comment: @JamesSheridan  That comment seems almost poignant now, in light of the more recent *Fantastic Four* remake.