# Has the Hulk ever held any Infinity Stone?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Is The Hulk powerful enough to wield any of the Infinity Stones? In *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble*,  he is shown to dominate a fight with both the Asgardians - Thor and Loki. Does that in any way indicate he is strong enough for the stones?

Comment: Related, possible dupes: [How does the Power Stone determine power?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85152/5184), [Why do you need to be powerful to wield an infinity stone?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85760/5184), [What is required to wield an infinity gem?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/64884/5184)

Comment: In *The Avengers/Avengers Assemble* we see Bruce Banner pick up Loki's Sceptre, which we learn in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* contains an Infinity Stone (the Mind Stone). That is the closest The Hulk has been to holding an Infinity Stone in the Marvel Cinematic Universe at the time of writing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, 5 of them, in the form of wearing them as gauntlets.

In the [Earth-1060(aka Ultimate Marvel universe) "Ultimates Disassembled" storyline](http://marvel.wikia.com/Bruce_Banner_%28Earth-1610%29).
(The 6th story arc of the 4th series of The Ultimate Comics series)

In this story the Infinity Gems actually combine to form two separate Gauntlets. The Hulk wears them to battle his former teammates.

spoiler responses to the comments

the 'missing gem'

> There are actually 8 gems in this story, 4 per glove, (the forth slots are hidden in this image). So Hulk had 5 of the 8 at this point. These gems are (in my opinion)  individually much less powerful that the MCU ones and only become cosmically powerful when all 8 are used together. It wasn't made entirely clear what all 5 of these gems could do (that I can read). They did know that the "gloves" allowed for matter transference, transmogrification and teleportation.

how they beat Hulk whilst he had these

> They didn't!. He won that battle easily and then handed the gloves to an ally of his.

[image]

Comment: That very well be the most terrifying thing that I have ever seen.

Comment: Interesting.  The MCU was recently revealed to have two Gauntlets, I didn't realize there was a comic precedent for that.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know which one he was missing in that scene?

Comment: How could they possibly defeat him?

Comment: There were six in the comics, in most universes (plus Ego). How did there end up being eight?