# What does it take to destroy a Celestial?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, celestials

The Marvel Comics' **[Celestials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_%28comics%29)** seem to be ridiculously hardy:

- From **Thaddeus'** answer to [Which Celestial's head is “Knowhere”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/73521/21267)

  > From what we know of the Celestials in our Universe, (in the famed, Thor 3300) when confronted by the power of Odin, wearing the Destroyer, which was imbued with the power of all of Earth's Skyfather deities, and using the fire giant's Surtur's magical sword, Twilight, Odin was unable to harm even one Celestial for more than a moment. The indestructible Destroyer and Surtur's sword were destroyed seconds later. The power to sunder the head from a Celestial (and make it stick) must be incalculable. <sup>[[1]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73523/21267)</sup>
- And from **diras2010**'s answer to [Which Celestial's head is “Knowhere”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/73521/21267)

  > The Celestials are not indestructible, however. During the Third Host, the Celestials used their combined might to slay one of their brethren for breach of conduct.<sup>[[2]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90599/21267)</sup>
- And from Wikipedia

  > The characters are almost totally invulnerable, and have only been harmed in rare instances before instantly regenerating<sup>[[3]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celestial_%28comics%29#Powers_and_abilities)</sup>

So, **what does it take to destroy a Celestial being?**

Either from the Comics, or the MCU.

Comment: According to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/90663/20774), you need the "combined might" of multiple celestials.

Comment: @Richard [Recursion](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?q=recursion)

Comment: I hope you're just asking for a friend...

Comment: @Keen Yes, yes I am. I mean, I'm not out to destroy any in the near future. And don't worry about the one I have tied up in my basement, we just playing around!

Comment: Old age... incredible, inconceivably old age.

Comment: Apparently you have to either cross the streams or divide by zero... the ancient texts are unclear on the matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that Asgardian magic can do so, or at least can enchant weapons with this power.  In *Uncanny Avengers #6*, Thor, under the guidance of Kang (disguised as Loki), uses Asgardian magic to enchant Thor's axe, Jarnbjorn.  Using a spell that requires Odin, or his blood, Jarnbjorn is enhanced such that it can pierce Celestial armor.  Then, in *Uncanny Avengers #7*, the Apocalypse Twins, wielding Jarnbjorn, kill a Celestial.  That issue also states:

> For the assassination of a Celestial has **never** occurred before...

Which indicates this hasn't happened before.  However, others have battled the Celestials...

Advanced technology (think cosmic race on the same scale as the Celestials) is also capable of doing the job.  In *Iron Man (Vol 5) #12*,

> 451

reveals that there was a war against the Celestials long ago, and that one of the weapons survived.  It was a nearly 5 mile tall exoskeleton called the Godkiller built by a race referred to as the Aspirants to kill Celestials.  In the next issue, it's implied it was used in the war, and was *quite effective*:

> This was the final battle of the Celestial war.  The Aspirants were desperate.  The Celestials were too.  The Godkiller turned the battle.  Sadly, as time would tell, it failed to win them the war.

The Aspirants stripped the Godkiller of crucial components, which were used in a civil war.

So there you go, either use Odin-derived Asgardian magic to kill a Celestial, or be an ancient race, and build a 5 mile tall suit of armor.  Either way will enable you to kill a Celestial.

Comment: I see, I see. Where do I get my hands on this 'god killer'? for, er, umm, research purposes... Yes research...