# How powerful are Celestials?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

I finally got around to watching *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* and it's the first I've heard of the Celestials. How powerful are the Celestials as a race in the Marvel Universe, compared to other God-like creatures like Asgardians, Thanos and Galactus?

Comment: This is widely opinion-based​; define "powerful" here? What makes someone more powerful than another?

Comment: @Jenayah I don't see how the power of a superhero is any more subjective than the strength of a human. You can measure both by looking at their feats. In fact I'm pretty sure I've come across an official ranking of Marvel heroes based on their power, in which God-like creatures like Celestials and Galactus are at the high end of the scale and enhanced humans (mutants) at the bottom of it.

Comment: Is Galactus in the MCU? I'm teetering on the edge of VTC here

Comment: @NKCampbell not yet but the question is scoped to MCU and comics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does it take to destroy a Celestial?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90663/what-does-it-take-to-destroy-a-celestial)

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This answer is from a purely Marvel Cinematic Universe perspective.

Celestials can control matter, move it around and manipulate it as they see fit, Ego created a whole planet around himself.

> **Ego:** Mmm, small "g," son. At least on the days I’m feeling humble as Drax. I don’t know where I came from exactly. First thing I remember is flickering… adrift in the cosmos utterly… and entirely alone. Over millions of years… I learned to control the molecules around me. I grew smarter and stronger. And I continued building from there… layer by layer… the very planet you walk on now.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

Even as much as they can create complex life systems.

> **Ego:** I’ve also got pain receptors, and a digestive system… and all the accompanying junk. I wanted to experience what it truly meant to be human… as I set out amongst the stars… until I found… what I sought. Life. I was not alone in the universe after all.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2*</sub>

On top of that, the power of a Celestial is what meant Peter could hold the Infinity Stone for as long as he could alone.

> **Nova Prime:** You are half Terran. Your mother was of earth. Your father, well, he's something very ancient we've never seen here before.
>
> **Gamora:** That could be why you were able to hold the stone for as long as you did.
>
> <sub>*Guardians of the Galaxy*</sub>

On top of that the Collector shows the Guardians a massive Celestial wielding the Power Stone and destroying a planet.

[image: A massive Celestial stood on a planet towering over it all in the vision]

On top of that Ego himself was the small brain structure we saw at the centre of his planet. He, however, was able to control matter all the way around the universe from projecting his bodies and also with the implants of himself he set off on the other planets.

Overall, depending on how you define power Celestials are by far the most powerful being we have seen in the MCU.

However, that’s an important disclaimer; power can be defined in different terms so Celestials may not have the combat power as some other races. But they certainly have a ***lot*** of power at their disposal. Just being able to wield the Power Stone on it’s own is enough to dictate them as a top power race.

Comment: Point of order. Thanos is the most powerful being we've seen in the MCU.

Comment: @Valorum Thanos with the full Infinity Gauntlet is. Thanos is a better fighter than Ego but he isn’t necessarily more powerful.

Comment: This is really just a list of the powers that Ego is shown to have in the movie, but I'm looking for more of a comparison between the power of Celestials and other-Godlike creatures like Odin and Thanos. Context from the comics would probably go a long way to establishing this.

Comment: @Prometheus of course it’s a list of powers of Celestials, how else are we to establish how powerful something is without listing their powers? A Celestial never comes into contact with the more powerful beings like Thanos or an Asgardian so there is no direct comparison to be made from the MCU which is where I’ve answered from.

Comment: My bad, I just realised I tagged this question MCU. I was looking for a broader look at Marvel media as of course the MCU is a lot more limited. Upvoted for what it is regardless.