# What race (species?) is Star Lord's dad?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

At the end of the new *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* Trailer we meet Star Lord's father:

Dad appears to be human. But Peter Quill's mother said in the first film that his father was a

> "being made of pure light".

**What race (species?) is Star Lord's father in the MCU?**

Comment: It was the 70's, there were drugs involved.... what she thought she saw is almost certainly not what was actually there.

Comment: According to various sources, such as the Guardians of the Galaxy v2's IMDB page, Kurt Russell will be playing Ego, the living planet.

Comment: Race: Planetoid

Comment: To be fair, Ego does not have a race or species - he's a one-off thing. You might as well ask what race or species Death or Eternity or Galactus belong to.

Comment: @Omegacron technically he's a two-off thing, since there's ego and alter-ego.

Comment: @Omegacron But is a Taan who bonded with the Sentience of the Universe!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## [A Celestial](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Celestials_(Race)) <sup><sub><sup>[1](http://marvel.com/universe/Celestials)</sup></sub></sup>

The film informs us that Ego, Star Lord' father, is in fact what is known as a **Celestial**.
<sub>This is not an official quote from the script but am almost 99% sure it's accurate</sub>

> Peter: A Celestial? Like a God?
>
> Ego: Small 'g'.

Ego seems to find the need to distinguish between a God and a god.

The below passage describes the plot of the film and how the Character in the Film relates to his Comic counterpart.

> Ego is not powerful himself, he needs an offspring to combine his powers with, so he can take over all the planets he has planted his "seedlings" to terraform and create extensions of himself.

---

<sub>Answer from before Film was released</sub>

From an interview with James Gunn, the director of *Guardians of the Galaxy*, he reveals that Ego, Star Lord's father is not only a living planet, but also a God. He also states his reasons for choosing Ego to be Star Lord's father instead of J'Son, like in the comics. (Emphasis mine)

#### Warning, the large gap in the middle spoils the main theme of the movie.

> Gunn told io9 of why he chose Comic-Con to reveal the information. “And I think one of the things I impressed upon people early on is the identity of Quill’s father is not the big stunner in this movie. I’m not leading it all to Darth Vader being Luke’s father in the third act reveal.
>
> > This is really about the relationship between [Star-Lord] and his father, **who happens to be a living planet**, and his other father, Yondu, who is an abusive jerk. It’s about the dysfunctional family triad that those three characters have. That’s the center of the movie.”
>
> “I didn’t like that in the comics J’Son is a king, and he also reeked  very much of Star Wars, so I didn’t want that same sort of thing,” Gunn   said. “I like the idea of **Quill’s father being an ancient, cosmic,   incredibly powerful being** who, just like Rocket, has problems connecting   to other people because [...] there’s nothing else like him. This   character has a hard time connecting to other people because **he’s a   god** who’s been alone for billions of years.” 
> <sub>[James Gunn   explains why Ego is Star Lord's Father](http://io9.gizmodo.com/james-gunn-explains-why-ego-is-star-lords-father-in-gua-1784456191)</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> Link to the official Marvel Wiki.

Comment: To be fair, a living planet that impregnates a woman and then takes off like a ding dong ditcher in the night might be considered an abusive jerk as well.

Comment: Does he have a lantern symbol mown across his belly button/equator?

Comment: I don't want to read the spoiler, since I will go see this movie, but that doesn't make any damn sense at all. Ego is a huge purple planet. Kurt Russell is not, in real life or in that trailer.

Comment: @DCShannon The best movies of the 1980s revolved around him.

Comment: @Terriblefan to be fair a living planet that stuck around to raise their kid might be worse, don't think people will take kindly when Quill's father crushes his son limbs from the waist down when dishing out some disciplinary spankings

Comment: Is this a different Ego from the Infinity Gem?

Comment: Yes, this is Ego the living planet, the infinity gem is something different, there isn't much about the infinity gem that is Ego.

Comment: If I remember right, there is a line in the movie, "a small-g god".

Comment: @Broklynite: That is Mogo, an entirely different living planet.  He's from DC, as are all Green Lanterns, while Ego is from Marvel.  They're both the token planet beings for their respective companies, though.  They probably hang out and get coffee from time to time.

Comment: @Jeff glad someone got the joke at least

Comment: In hindsight, Ego was also a different kind of abusive jerk, because (spoilers).

Answer (score 8):

## Celestial, apparently

In the movie, *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol 2.*, Ego refers to himself as a "[**Celestial**][1]":

> Gamora: You destroyed 1000 ships without even a suit, who can do that?
> Ego: I'm what's known as a Celestial, sweetheart
> Peter: Wait, a Celestial? As in a God?
> Ego: With a small "g". At least on the days I have the modesty of Drax.  
> <sup>-*Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol 2.* [paraphrased]</sup>

In the movie, although [Ego](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Ego_the_Living_Planet) is apparently a [Celestial](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Celestials), he has manifested himself as a living planet as well as a being of human form as he can manipulate matter around himself (or his consciousness):

[image: Image of the actor Kurt Russell portraying "Ego" from the movie Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol 2.]
<sup>[img src](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/0/07/Ego_at_last.png/revision/latest?cb=20170301050123)</sup>

[image: Image of "Ego the Living Planet" from the Marvel Comics. A large planetoid with a seemingly human-featured face]
<sup>[img src](http://www.geek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Ego-The-Living-Planet.jpg)</sup>

### Being of pure "white" light

Ego mentions on the movie that it is some sort of "white light" which powers him and enables him to maintain his form. We also see that this "white light" is utilised fairly often by Ego himself

> and eventually by Peter Quill / Starlord as well,

as some sort of weaponised power source.

What exactly this "white light" is is unknown at this point, but it seems to me that it is Ego's actual consciousness itself. It has the power to create and to destroy, but is never stated exactly what the light or power source actually is.

---

### What even is a Celestial, and is Ego actually one?

O.k., to be honest, I'm not 100% convinced that Ego is *actually* a Celestial, merely that he says he is.

**What *is* a Celestial?**
The [Celestials](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73523/21267) (in the comics) are:

> a star-faring race of humanoid aliens who possess untold cosmic power. Standing two thousand feet tall, the Celestials are clad in full body armor. No Earth being has ever seen what they look like beneath their armor or knows their origin.
> <sup>*-[Celestials](http://marvel.com/universe/Celestials), Marvel Universe Wiki.*</sup>

[image: Image capture of a group of "Celestials" gathered around, standing as tall as the Pyramids of Giza]
<sup>[img src](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/10/Celestial_4th_host.jpg)</sup>

And are even similar within the MCU:

> The Celestials were an ancient race of armored, humanoid beings with god-like powers.
> <sup>*-[Celestials](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Celestials), Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki.*</sup>

This is **Eson the Searcher**, from the flashback scene where The Collector explains the origins of the Power Stone to the Guardians in the *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 1* movie:

[image: Image grab from the movie Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 1 depicting a giant armoured "Celestial" being called "Eson the Searcher"]
<sup>[img src](https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/b/b7/Esonsearcher.png/revision/latest?cb=20141126104220)</sup>

**What about Ego?**
Yeah, so then we have Ego, who looks nothing like the rest of the very few Celestials that we do know about, was born as some sort of single-cell organism who multiplied himself; both by manipulating matter around him to increase his own manifestation, as well as planting seeds on many worlds to multiply himself.

According to our resident Marvel expert, Thaddeus Howze:

> ... The pedigree of the Celestials overall is very rare. Few have been named and even fewer have been named and killed in the Marvel Universe.
> <sup>*-Which Celestial's head is "Knowhere"?, answer by [Thaddeus Howze](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73523/21267).*</sup>

Ego says the he doesn't know where he came from, but at some point he just *was*, and that he'd spent millions of years looking for other life. Finally finding this other life he'd been looking for.

What concerns me is that

> ... there were once billions of Celestials in the universe and due to a conflict with another early developing race called the Aspirants and the release of a super-weapon called the Godkiller, millions of Celestials were destroyed. It is likely the origin of Knowhere is a remnant from that first conflict billions of years ago.
> <sup>*-Which Celestial's head is "Knowhere"?, answer by [Thaddeus Howze](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73523/21267).*</sup>

So if there were billions of them:

- Why was Ego alone?
- Where did those other billions come from?
- Did they all find each other too, but Ego just happened to miss them?
- Did Ego come to being much after the rest of the Celestials had come to an end?
- Why did he feel the need to multiply himself, like a virus?

Those are the questions that keep me up at night.

I may be nitpicking and due to the mysterious long-lost nature of the Celestials, it's convenient for the creators and writers to make things up as they go, and that we should take their word for it, but this particular point is just hard for me to reconcile.

---

Comment: #StayWokePeople

Comment: I'm with you - I don't think Ego was a Celestial (aka the race of Celestials that walked in armor everywhere), just a very powerful being (probably more powerful than the Celestials, actually).

Comment: I think they're remixing the associations from the comics, so we can't really rely on them too much.  Ego was part of the [Elders of the Universe](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Elders_of_the_Universe_members) - but so was a character we've already met, the Collector.

Comment: Incidentally, how can no one know what a Celestial looks like under its armor if there's literally a mining colony inside one's head?

Comment: "This is Eson the Searcher, from the Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 1 movie:"  where / when?

Answer (score 7):

*Note: This answer is true for the Marvel Comics Universe, which has a different canon than the Marvel Cinematic Universe (MCU), as pointed out by Edlothiad in their post.

The Marvel wiki does not specifically state Star Lord's Father's species (Called [J'Son](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/J%27son_(Earth-616)) by the wiki), but it does say that he was born to the previous emperor of the [Spartoi](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Spartoi_Empire) people, and that he himself was heir to the throne. This means he is most logically Spartoi.


J'Son as Emperor of Spartoi:

[image]

Comment: Different continuity, Olorinfistopheles.

Comment: Also: the Spatroi share ancestry with the Shi'ar who are avian descended, so they're a separate species from humanity.

Comment: I suspect the first sentence is supposed to say that the wiki does not "state Star Lord's Father's *race*".