# How does Ego's ship do this?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In *Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2*,

> Ego's egg-shaped ship appears and destroys the High Priestess' entire remaining fleet with what seems like a single energy burst.

**How is Ego's ship able to do this?**

Additionally:

- What relevant descriptive information can you share about Ego's ship?
- Do the comics provide relevant information about Ego's ship?

Answer (score 16):

**tl;dr** It wasn't really his ship that did it, it was *him*; given his 'God-Mode' powers.

---

### IDDQD

Well, Ego is a supremely powerful being, [**he's actually a Celestial**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/158450/21267). In a sense Ego has "[IDDQD](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/iddqd)" or 'God-Mode' abilities with a bit of "[IDKFA](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=idkfa)" mixed-in. As he explains to the Guardians, it seems to just be a thing that he can do:

> Gamora: You destroyed 1000 ships without even a suit, who can do that?
>   Ego: I'm what's known as a Celestial, sweetheart
>   Peter: Wait, a Celestial? As in a God?
>   Ego: With a small "g". At least on the days I have the modesty of Drax.
> <sup>-*Guardians of the Galaxy: Vol. 2.* [paraphrased]</sup>

It seems to me that it's not really his ship that can do that, rather it's *him*. In fact, everything he has - his ship, his planet, his physical body - is in fact *him*, or rather a manifestation and extension of his self.

If you recall, in the scene where Ego destroys the Sovereign fleet, Ego is actually seen standing atop his ship, straddling it like some sort of steed, with harnesses and everything. It's not clear where the white blast type attack comes from, but his dialogue with Gamora seems to suggest that it was him that did the damage, not the ship.

In fact, in subsequent scenes, when Ego utilises his "power", he is seen doing so without any aides or weapons; as does

> Peter, once he realises his potential too.

### Skynet *is* the virus

Or rather, **Ego *is* the ship.**

This is where it gets tricky: [Ego](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_the_Living_Planet#Film) is based on the [comics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_the_Living_Planet), however it is not a verbatim adaptation. Ego seems to have some extended abilities; namely his physical 'human-like' form and other extensions - such as his ship. Additionally, Ego from the movie is said to be a Celestial, whereas the comics version is not.

This is why, apart from the information we're given in the movie and any additional information given to us via the creators, it's not possible to give more insight about his ship or other abilities.

However, from what we *can* see, his ship:

- Can travel at FTL speeds

  - Doesn't seem to require the use of "jumps" to travel from **Berhert** (the planet that the Guardians crash-land on after the Sovereign attack) to Ego's Planet
- Looks like an egg
- Can transport people within it (duh)
- Can transform its shape

  - To create an opening as a door
  - To create a moving platform which acts as a travelator

Comment: I like the last point: "Looks like an egg."

Comment: Skynet is the virus.

Answer (score 3):

#### Despite the appearance of a using a ship, Ego doesn't actually need one to move between worlds. Using the power primordial, Ego's abilities are limited only by his imagination.

[image]

His starship is nothing more than camouflage, a pretense he creates to make people underestimate him and treat him as just another humanoid moving around the Universe.

- In fact, any construction of Ego's is literally nothing more than his planet's programmable matter being used to create a device which acts according to his will. If Ego needs to move someone between planets (in this case, Mantis) he can create an environment which can do so.
- The Sovereign starships were no match for the power Ego can access via his unique biology as a primordial organism. While he lay claim to the idea he is a Celestial (and in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, he may indeed be one) it is unlikely he should be classified as a Celestial since he was able to be defeated by the likes of the Guardians of the Galaxy.
- True Celestials could only be defeated by other primordial beings like themselves such as Galactus, Infinity, or other such cosmic aspects. It is more likely Ego was a being of immense capacity, whose use of technology and genetic engineering made him as powerful as an organic being could be.

With his cosmic powers, Ego is not limited to using warp gates, jump systems or any other such technology used by the Ravagers, Kree or the Xandarians. Using his own power primordial, he could easily overcome every aspect of the Sovereign technology with no true effort on his part.

#### In the Comics

Ego does not deign to use such constructions such as starships, even though he is capable of doing so. When he meets Thor for the first time, he reveals his capacity to create organic constructs which resemble Asgardians seconds after meeting the thunder god. As a rule, Ego is inclined to simply fly his moon-sized body to wherever he wants to be and then do whatever he likes once he arrives there.

[image]

- In Thor #132 (1966) Ego confronts Galactus for the first time and with the help of Thor, the two drive off the Devourer of Worlds. These two would battle again and again over the decades.
- Galactus would later create a propulsion unit and mount it on Ego's surface to drive him away from civilization. Ego would later take control of said technology and become even MORE mobile than he had been before.