# Is there any precedent for Ego in the MCU differing from Celestials in the Comics?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, celestials

In the second Guardians of the Galaxy film, we learn that Ego is a Celestial. This is big deviation from the comics universe, but that is fine, this is a different universe. However, my understanding is that the MCU universe still belongs to the same Marvel multiverse as the all the comic universes.

In the X-Termination crossover, we see that originally there was one universe, containing the Celestials and that they split it apart into the multiverse to imprison the Exterminators between the universes. In fact Celestials seem to be commonly portrayed as being giant robot things and having powers that can reach across different universes within the multiverse, so one would expect them to be similar even in the MCU.

Ego on the other hand appears alone in the MCU, with no way to reach Celestials in other universes, and has come into being entirely within the MCU. He also takes a drastically different form.

**Is there any precedent in the comics of other Celestials deviating this much from the common portrayal?**

He does appear to 'seed' life on planets around the universe like other celestials, albeit in a slightly more conventional form.

Comment: The bold sentence seems a bit at odds with the title and rest of the body. Do you want a comparison between film Ego and the usual comic Celestials, or do you want to know about other times that there has been an unusual Celestial?

Comment: @DCShannon the latter, clarified the title.

Comment: “and has come into being entirely within the MCU” — well, we can’t really be sure about that, can we.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Possibly, on that part I'm assuming its implication here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159538/how-does-ego-know-what-a-celestial-is?rq=1. I guess maybe its not so clear and he may just have become isolated and alone in the MCU over time?

Comment: @Jack: yeah I just figure there’s nothing to preclude any future author from deciding that the entire MCU was created by a Reed Richards experiment gone wrong, or by an odd chemical reaction in Hank Pym’s liver, or by Stan Lee while wearing a Watcher costume, or whatever. Multiverses are not the place to look for consistent rule-sets defined ahead of time.

Comment: There is still the possibility that Ego errs about what he actually is and that we will learn about actual Celestials later. In fact, his powers seem some magnitudes off.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Yeah, possibly, thats one of the reasons why I'm interested to see if there has been any precedent, although we can probably expect the MCU to be breaking more than a few.