# Is there another meaning to the name Knowhere?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, comics, avengers-infinity-war

In *Infinity War* a number of places, when first shown, have a subtitle showing the name of the location.

> Obviously when hoping to get a step ahead of Thanos, the Guardians of the Galaxy went to see Taneleer Tivan who they were told was given the Reality Stone (The Aether) by the Asgardians after the events of *Thor: The Dark World* the subtitle of the place was ***Knowhere***

I can't help but notice that while it's a play on the word **Nowhere** and that's how the characters say it, if I was to spell it I would be putting 2 W's in like Knowwhere (in fact I have to keep pausing when I do this question remembering it's one W) and so to me it looks like it's ***Know-Here*** as opposed to ***Know-Where***.

So I am wondering, whether in the MCU or in the comics, is there another meaning to the name Knowhere which explains why it looks like Know-Here as opposed to Know-Where?

Comment: I always thought it was a way of saying they didn't _know where_ they were or where they went, but that's just my interpretation. I'm interested in seeing if there's any significance besides fun wordplay.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re asking? Are you asking why you can’t read it the way it’s pronounced? I personally think it’s quite clearly kno-where when looking at it based on its pronunciation. Also sorry for the tags, had a weird thought but reverted it.

Comment: Related: [Which Celestial's head is “Knowhere”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/73521/21267)

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't be spelled "Know-Where" because that is awkward and grammatically incorrect.

"Knowhere" is also grammatically incorrect, but it is said the same way as the proper "Nowhere," and incorporates a pun on "know" and "where."

Perhaps I'm reaching too far, but the source of the pun may be the fact that Knowhere is the skull of a giant creature - the main cavity is presumably the brain cavity, or the repository of knowledge in a creature.

Comment: What's funny is I have no issues with "Knowhere", but reflexively want to read "nowhere" as "now here", especially with the "Nowhere" capitalization.